# How to remove old program from arduino uno kit and upload new program in it?

Tags: arduino

I have upload code in arduino for a project but know i want to remove this code from arduino kit and want to upload new code which has different functionality than old one. So i can do it. Please help. :)

Comment: Just upload the new one.

Comment: Will old one remove automatically ? I am asking because there is a question in my mind , if i do that so may be arduino kit damage or create errors.... :/

Comment: Yes, the old program will be removed automatically.

Comment: thank you #Eugene_Sh & #Jay_Blanchard :)

Answer (score 5):

When you upload new code to the Arduino it flashes the memory (wipes any existing code previously stored).

So to answer your question, just write your new code and press upload.